# Tomcat cannot find class for my REST web service class

Tags: eclipse, jersey, tomcat8

I create a simple web service using Eclipse WTP. Tomcat version is 8.5 and Java is 1.8.

I downloaded Jersey 2.27. When starting the Server from Eclipse, I receive the following **error**:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: A class file of the class name,
>   my.simple.webservice.SimpleWebService is identified but the class
>   could not be found.

Any helps to resolve this is very much appreciated.

Searching on StackOverflow and other site did not return any useful information.

My web service looks like this:

```
 package my.simple.webservice;

    ...imports ...

    @Path("/")

    public class SimpleWebService {

    @POST

    @Path("/service")

    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response consumeService(InputStream incomingData) {
        /* 
                 *do stuff here with the JSON
                 */
        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(myStringBuilder.toString()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/verify")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response verifyRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {
        String result = "My Simple web service Successfully started..";

        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.simple.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You should not accept answers that do not answer your question. If you solved the problem yourself, you can answer your own question, and accept it after a couple days. The purpose of accepting an answer is for others searching for the same problem. They look for the accepted answer to find the solution to their similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete your project's build folder
2. then `clean` `install` by maven build
3. Run your application

<sub>If it still does not work let me know, i will replicate the problem on my system.</sub>

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your replay. I restarted Eclipse and now the server starts ok but when I tried to access my service http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/api/verify,  I got a 404 not found reply from Tomcat

Comment: set a default rest api path in your web.xml lke below `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: when you call your api like -> http://something.com/project/rest then your default method of the resource file will fire. so no 404 happen.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I have that set up already as you can see in my web.xml. I have also confirmed that the context root is correct so SimpleWebService/api/verify is the correct path.

Comment: The 404 Not Found Error is an HTTP response status code , which indicates that the requested resource could not be found. there is some mapping problem rest all seems ok, wait let me dig more.

Comment: is issue same with localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/api/service ?

Comment: I apologize, I some how deleted the @Path annotation in my source file. Now everything is work as expected. Thanks Common Man for your helps!